# Using dictionary to deserialise

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a VB.NET program that retrieves information from a Firebase Realtime Database.

The code below gets the data from the 'information' node:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim resp = Await client.GetTaskAsync("information")
    Debug.WriteLine("Info: " & resp.Body)
    Dim getData = resp.ResultAs(Of Dictionary(Of String, Data1))

    For Each i In getData
         Debug.WriteLine("Name: " & i.Value.id)
    Next
End Sub

Public Class Data1
    Public id As String
    Public name As String
    Public address As String
    Public age As String
End Class
```

Output from the data retrieval is:

Info: {"task1":{"address":"3","age":"4","id":"1","name":"2"},"task2":{"address":"3","age":"4","id":"1","name":"2"},"task3":{"address":"3","age":"4","id":"1","name":"2"},"task4":{"address":"3","age":"4","id":"1","name":"2"},"task5":{"address":"3","age":"4","id":"1","name":"2"}}

So I know that information is being collected correctly. The issue comes when I try to use the data to generate a list. I use `.ResultAs(Of Dictionary(Of String, Data1))`to break it down with the class 'Data1'. Key is ok for each node e.g. "task1" - but values for 'address' or 'age' etc. are null.

Can anyone shed any light on where I'm going wrong?